# Given positive $x,y$ such that $x > y$ and $\sqrt{x} \sqrt{y}(x-y) = x+y $, find minimum $(x+y)$

Tags: inequality, optimization, proof-writing, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I am given positive numbers $x, y$ such that $x > y$ and $\sqrt{x} \sqrt{y}(x-y) = x+y $. I need to find the minimum value of $(x+y)$. Here is my try. Using AM-GM inequality for nonnegative numbers, I have

$$ 
\frac{(x+y)}{2} \geqslant \sqrt{x} \sqrt{y}  
$$

$$
 \sqrt{x} \sqrt{y}(x-y) \geqslant 2 \sqrt{x} \sqrt{y}   
 \\ \therefore (x-y) \geqslant 2  
$$

So, I have been able to arrive at this conclusion. But I am stuck here. Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like $(x+y)\leqslant (2y+2)$ and $\inf_y (2y+2)=2$. I don't think the minimum exists for $y>0$.

Comment: The problem was on Brilliant.org. So, I doubt they will post a problem which is not well defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By AM-GM
$$(x+y)^2=xy(x-y)^2=\frac{1}{4}\cdot4xy(x-y)^2\leq\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{4xy+(x-y)^2}{2}\right)^2=\frac{(x+y)^4}{16},$$
which gives $$x+y\geq4.$$
The equality occurs for $(x-y)\sqrt{xy}=x+y$ and $4xy=(x-y)^2,$ which gives $$(x,y)=(2+\sqrt2,2-\sqrt2),$$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Comment: I also got the answer an hour after I posted the question. I let $u = x+y $ and $ v = xy $. But yours is shorter than mine.

Answer (score 2):

put $x=r^2{cos}^2a$  and $y=r^2{sin}^2a$ also let $a$ belong to $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

thus we have to find max value of $r^2$

plugging the values in the given equation  and simplifying using basic trig formulas we have $r^4(cosa)(sina)(cos2a)=r^2$ or

$ r^2=\frac{4}{sin(4a)} \ge 4$

Comment: Nice solution. But shouldn't we be careful about the conditions on $r$ and $a$. How do we make sure that $\sin(4a) > 0 $ here ?

Comment: @user9026 as $r^2$ is positive sin(4a) must be positive

Comment: But how we prove rigorously that $ \sin(4a) > 0 $ ?

Comment: @user9026  i dont think  i have understood what you mean by rigorous proof. the given condition btw x,y is satisfied only if sin4a>0 as mentioned in the above comment

Comment: I think you plugged $\sqrt{x} = r \cos(a)$. Shouldn't it be $ \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{ r^2 \cos(a)^2 } = | r \cos(a) | $

Comment: @user9026 i have added something . I hope it solves the problem .

Answer (score 1):

Hint : put $x=\alpha \cosh^2(x)$ and $y=\alpha\sinh^2(x)$ the condition becomes :

$$\alpha=\tanh(x)+\frac{1}{\tanh(x)}$$

The expression is :

$$x+y=\Big(\tanh(x)+\frac{1}{\tanh(x)}\Big)\frac{1+\tanh^2(x)}{1-\tanh^2(x)}$$

Solving it we found $x+y\geq 4$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\sqrt{xy}\left(x-y\right)=x+y$

let $yx=c$ , where $c>0$.

$$\sqrt{c}\left(x^{2}-c\right)=x^{2}+c$$
$$x^{2}-\frac{\left(c+1+2\sqrt{c}\right)}{\left(c-1\right)}c=0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -[1]$$

Let a function $$F(x,c)=x^{2}-\frac{\left(c+1+2\sqrt{c}\right)}{\left(c-1\right)}c$$ be defined. Then $$\frac{\partial F(x,c)}{\partial c}=0$$ at a constant $x$ gives us $c \approx 2.618 \implies x \approx 3.33 $ ( using $[1]$ ) . So, $$x+\frac{c}{x}\geqslant 4$$
$$min(x+y)=4$$

when $x=2+\sqrt{2} \text{ and } y=2-\sqrt2$ as pointed out.

Comment: the tag is algebra precalculus!

Comment: @HariRamakrishnanSudhakar where?

Comment: i guess it was changed when someone edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Making

$$
\cases{
u = x+y\\
v = x-y
}
$$

we have

$$
\sqrt{u^2-v^2}=2\frac uv
$$

so

$$
u^2 = \frac{v^4}{v^2-4}
$$

etc.